# Reputation changes points message not showing or disappearing swiftly

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed

Since a couple of days I noted that reputation changes points message is not showing or disappearing swiftly (I'm not sure yet wich is it).

I can only see that the number is higher or lower, without any message.

Is it just me (my internet connection is quite unreliable), or is a bug?

Comment: Possibly the same: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367961/im-not-getting-reputation-notifications

Comment: This was related to the [bug that was mentioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367961/im-not-getting-reputation-notifications) in the comment above and has been fixed.